# Touching on the particular sprite from the spritesheet

Tags: android, cocos2d

I want to click on the particular sprite from the sprite sheet. For instance i have fruits sprite sheet i want to click on the particular fruit.

Thanks,
Jubin Mehta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution would be:

1. Get the cursor position.
2. Transform the position into the tiles local coordinate space.

   pixelPositionX = cursorPositionX - (tilePositionInWorldX - screenPositionX)

   pixelPositionY = cursorPositionY - (tilePositionInWorldY - screenPositionY)
3. Find out if the position is inside the tile.

   tilePositionOnSpritesheetX < pixelpositionX < tilePositionOnSpritesheetX + tileSizeX

   tilePositionOnSpritesheetY < pixelpositionY < tilePositionOnSpritesheetY + tileSizeY
4. If it is, check if the alpha value of the pixel at that position is over a certain treshold.

Step 4 is optional, without it, you're checking against the tiles bounding rectangle, with it, clicking is pixel perfect.

Please note that all positions and sizes are assumed to be in pixels.

Comment: Just found a related question that goes into the implementation details for cocos2d: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637743/how-can-i-detect-touch-in-cocos2d